# SQL: Creating a View for 2 Tables and 1 Reference Table

Tags: sql, view, left-join

I got a novice SQL question for which I cannot seem to find an answer. Please allow me to explain with a made-up (but relevant) scenario:

Let's say I have two tables: `TBL_HOME` and `TBL_WORK`. Both tables have a set of columns that are mostly related to the respective place's address. I also have one reference table called `REF_CITY` that simply has two columns, `CITY_ID` and `CITY_NAME`. I need a View that has (among others) the `CITY_NAME` of both locations.

I know how to get the `CITY_NAME` for one of the 2 tables:

```
// e.g., Get city name for HOME
SELECT c.CITY_NAME AS HOME_CITY
FROM TBL_HOME h
LEFT JOIN REF_CITY c ON h.CITY_ID = c.CITY_ID
```

But I'm at a loss on how the `CITY_NAME` for both places can be added to the same View as the reference to `c.CITY_NAME` is already made for one location.

Comment: Is there a connection between these two tables? i.e. is there an ID in TBL_HOME that joins to TBL_WORK?

Comment: @rdbradshaw - Actually, yes. TBL_WORK has a FK column that contains the PK of TBL_HOME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can complete this by joining the two tables together, then joining to the reference table twice. Using your `TBL_HOME` and `TBL_WORK` example:

```
SELECT CityHOME.CITY_NAME as HomeCity, CityWork.CITY_NAME as WorkCity
FROM TBL_HOME HOME
LEFT JOIN TBL_WORK WORK on HOME.PrimaryKey = WORK.ForeignKey
LEFT JOIN REF_CITY CityHOME on CityHOME.CITY_ID = HOME.CITY_ID
LEFT JOIN REF_CITY CityWork on CityWork.CITY_ID = WORK.CITY_ID
```